# How to define the completeness of stochastic search problems?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

Can we just define it to be the search with the probability limit of find a solution to be 1?

Answer (score 1):

short answer: yes

longer answer: In order to claim a search algorithm [even stochastic] is "complete" you must show that if there is an answer, the algorithm will find an answer, in a finite time.
This means, you must show that if there is an answer, there cannot be, with any probability, a non-finishing [or finishing with wrong answer] path. So, you need to show that a solution will be found with probability 1 [exactly! not approximately!], to show a stochastic algorithm is "complete"

For example, [steepest ascent hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing#Variants) with side walks [you can go to a neighbor with the same utility value] - is not complete, since you can enter an infinite loop and never find any solution. However, if you limit the number of side walks to a finite number `K`, it is complete, because if there is a local minimum, eventually the algorithm will find one, with probability 1.

Comment: But think of a local platform of the steepest ascent hill climbing. Even if we limit the number of sidewalks up to k, there is still a probability of being restricted on that platform, though that probability goes to zero after infinite steps. So how can we say in a finite steps we can find the solution with probability exactly one?

Comment: Is this the same as saying that the probability of success approaches 1 in the limit when the search steps go towards infinitiy? But then can you say "a solution will be found with p=1"?